# How does Edwards curve used for generating public key look like?

Tags: cardano-address, eddsa, ed25519, private-key, public-key

What equation suitable for generation of a public key is used for Edwards curve `Ed25519`?

The problem is the following – info on [Edwards Elliptic Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve) on Wikipedia page presents an equation `y^2 + x^2 = 1 + d * y^2 * x^2` that doesn't allow us to plot a curve depicted on the first picture.

So, what equation is used for `Ed25519`? **This one?**

```
y^2 + x^2 = 1 - d * y^2 * x^2
```

[image]

**Or this one?**

```
y^2 + x^2 = 1 + d * y^2 * x^2
```

[image]

I haven't found any documentation covering this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation of the Edwards curve is

[image: ax^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2]

for Ed25519
a = -1, d = -121665/121666.

The curve is also living in the prime field. The equation is [image]

I could not plot this equation in geograba, I guess due to the nature of the prime field over which the equation is defined.(?)

Comment: I think IOHK used different `a` and `d` values for Ed25519 equation. As far as we can easily build a Bitcoin curve (`secp256k1`) over definite field using its native equation `y^2 = x^3 + 7`, we'll also be able to build a Cardano curve.